# I'm facing a error while installing Npm Multer for uploading files using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, multer, multer-s3

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN task-manager@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN task-manager@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager\node_modules\.bcrypt.DELETE\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.nodenpm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager\node_modules\.bcrypt.DELETE\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager\node_modules\.bcrypt.DELETE\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager\node_modules\.bcrypt.DELETE\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'D:\\Rakesh Folder\\NodeCourse\\task-manager\\node_modules\\.bcrypt.DELETE\\lib\\binding\\napi-v3\\bcrypt_lib.node'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Rakesh Folder\\NodeCourse\\task-manager\\node_modules\\.bcrypt.DELETE\\lib\\binding\\napi-v3\\bcrypt_lib.node',
npm ERR!   parent: 'task-manager'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
PS D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager> npm i multer
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN task-manager@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN task-manager@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager\node_modules\.bcrypt.DELETE\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.nodenpm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager\node_modules\.bcrypt.DELETE\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager\node_modules\.bcrypt.DELETE\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Rakesh Folder\NodeCourse\task-manager\node_modules\.bcrypt.DELETE\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'D:\\Rakesh Folder\\NodeCourse\\task-manager\\node_modules\\.bcrypt.DELETE\\lib\\binding\\napi-v3\\bcrypt_lib.node'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Rakesh Folder\\NodeCourse\\task-manager\\node_modules\\.bcrypt.DELETE\\lib\\binding\\napi-v3\\bcrypt_lib.node',
npm ERR!   parent: 'task-manager'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AnneRakesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-13T15_12_05_270Z-debug.log
```

Pease help me.
I'm facing this issue while installing by cmd `npm i multer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation this helped:

Before proceeding to execute these commands close all VS Code instances.

1. clean cache with

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
2. install the latest version of npm globally as admin:

   ```
   npm install -g npm@latest --force
   ```
3. clean cache with

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```

Try to install your component once again.

If this doesn't work, you may temporarily disable your antivirus program and try again.